# import csv with google apps script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i need help,

i found this code to import csv in google sheets with apps script. it's work find but i'd like to import in another sheet to the same file.

i can't find the code to enter number ( gid ) of my sheet

```
function myFunction() {
  function importData()
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = 'https://your-data-source.csv';
    var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }
  importData();
}
```

[exampel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9ITl.png)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the CSV data to the specification sheet in the active Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.
- From `i can't find the code to enter number ( gid ) of my sheet`, you want to choose the sheet using the sheet ID (gid).

#### Modification points:

- In order to put the values to the specific sheet, you can achieve it by modifying `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');` to  `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('importCSV');` from your sample image.
- If you want to chose the sheet using the sheet ID (gid), you can use the script like `var sheet = ss.getSheets().filter(s => s.getSheetId() == gid);`.
- In your script, each row is put to the sheet in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high. You can modify your for loop as `sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);`.

When the above points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, the CSV data is put to the specific sheet using the sheet ID (gid).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var url = 'https://your-data-source.csv';
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);

  var gid = "1234567890";  // Please set your sheet ID (gid).
  var sheet = ss.getSheets().filter(s => s.getSheetId() == gid);
  if (sheet.length == 1) {
    sheet[0].getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

or, you can also achieve your goal by modifying `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');` to  `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('importCSV');`. In this modified script, the CSV data is put to the sheet `importCSV`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var url = 'https://your-data-source.csv';
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('importCSV');  // Please set the sheet name.
  sheet[0].getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

#### Note:

- As the additional information, when you want to put the CSV data to a sheet in other Spreadsheet, you can achieve this by modifying from `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` to `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###Spreadsheet title###");`.

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))